# cinを用いて複素数に数字を入力するコードが、 Visual Studio だとエラーになる

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
complex<int> p;
int m;

cin >> p.real() >> p.imag();
cout << p.real() << p.imag();

return 0;

}
```

このコードはg++(gcc version 4.8.4)では問題なく実行できますが、Visual Studio Community 2015上ではエラー(C2678)となりますが、なぜこのような違いが生じるのでしょうか。

> エラー    C2678   二項演算子 '>>': 型 'std::istream' の左オペランドを扱う演算子が見つかりません (または変換できません) (新しい動作; ヘルプを参照)。

Comment: 皆様ご回答ありがとうございました。
疑問が解決し、嬉しく思います。
今後はC++14に準拠した書き方にしていきたいと思います。

Comment: 解決したなら**承認**をして頂けるとありがたいです。承認すればあなたの信用度がが2つ増え、承認された方の信用度が15上がります。また、解決したとの表明にもなります…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC++2015でコンパイルエラーになるのは、`real()`/`imag()`がC++14からconstexpr関数に変わり、戻り値である定数`constexpr T`に書き込めないからです。

```
// C++14
constexpr T real() const;
constexpr T imag() const;
```

GCC 4.8.4でコンパイルエラーにならないのは、まだC++14に対応していないバージョンだからですが、標準では戻り値は**参照ではない**変数`T`なので、書き込んでも意味がありません。

```
// C++03
T real() const;
T imag() const;
```

GCC 4.8.4というかlibstdc++が参照を返すようになっていたので[期待した動作をしていた](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iKshxofEq5NwXxBx)かもしれませんが、[標準では期待した動作になりません](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KHrKrWtLqnKKBxlH)。

```
// GCC 4.8.x
T &real();
const T &real() const;
T &imag();
const T &imag() const;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::complex::real()`](http://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/complex/complex/real.html) は

```
T real() const;                 // (1) C++11 まで
constexpr T real() const;       // (1) C++14 から
```

とC++14から仕様変更されています。Visual Studio 2015ではC++14に準拠しconstexpr関数になっているため`operator >>()`で書き込むことはできません。

そもそもC++11以前でもconst関数なので書き込む行為そのものが間違っています。G++では問題なく実行できたとのことですが、（コンパイラー依存ではなく）ライブラリの実装依存です。